# PHP print page on server side

Tags: php, printing

I want to print a page on the server side(via php). I think the best way is doing this by command(so shellexecute). But is there a command to print a page on windows?

Comment: _I want to print a page on the server side(via php)_ What does it mean ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you like to print a prepared Image (which you could create with PHP :) you could use [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/).

> i_view32.exe c:\foldername\image.jpg /print